# Trying to run a pice of code in a separated Thread

Tags: java, swing

I'm trying to make an simple Mp3 player in Java (Swing) for study purposes, and I'm really trying my best NOT to break the 'Single Responsibility Principle' regarding classes, and I seem to be stuck somehow.

My problem : After the song is completed, I want to proceed to the next song.
My player instance has a play method that it must run is a separate thread. This instance has a isComplete() method, that can be run is a while loop.

The player instance is located in the class "UserMainFunctions" that knows nothing about other classes.

Here's the code :

```
public final class UserMainFunctions implements MainFunctions {

MP3Tagger mp3Tagger = new MP3Tagger();
private FileInputStream fis;
private Player player;
private String currentPath;

public void stop() {
    if (getPlayer() != null) {
        getPlayer().close();
    }
}


@Override
public void play(String path) {

    // setCurrentPath(path);
    if (path != null) {
        try {
            stop();
            setFis(new FileInputStream(currentPath));
            setPlayer(new Player(getFis()));
            new Thread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        getPlayer().play();
                        while(getPlayer().isComplete()) {
                            ///increment and play


                        }

                    } catch (JavaLayerException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            }).start();

        } catch (FileNotFoundException | JavaLayerException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println("Nothing to play!");
    }

}

public String getCurrentPath() {
    return currentPath;
}

public void setCurrentPath(String currentPath) {
    this.currentPath = currentPath;
}

@Override
public List<String> getID3V1TAG(String path) {
    if (path != null) {
        return mp3Tagger.getID3V1TAG_List(path);
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}

@Override
public void openDir() {


}

public Player getPlayer() {
    return player;
}

public void setPlayer(Player player) {
    this.player = player;
}

public FileInputStream getFis() {
    return fis;
}

public void setFis(FileInputStream fis) {
    this.fis = fis;
}
}
```

Then I have the code that contains the UI display :

```
public class UI_Display extends JFrame {

public UI_Display() {
    initialize();
}

public JButton getButtons(String btnName) {
        switch(btnName) {
        case "Pause" :
            return getBtnPause();
        case "Play" : 
            return getBtnPlay();
        case "Stop" :
            return getBtnStop();
        case "Open" : 
            return getBtnEjectOpen();
        case "OpenDir" :
            return getBtnOpenDir();
        case "Prev" :
            return getBtnPrev();
        case "Next" :
            return getBtnNext();
            default : 
                System.out.println("No such button!");
                return null;
        }
    }

    public void setCellRenderer(int newIdex) {
        this.jList_songList.setCellRenderer(new DefaultListCellRenderer() {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1676346144422213946L;

            public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList<?> list, Object value, int index,
                    boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {

                super.getListCellRendererComponent(list, value, index, isSelected, cellHasFocus);
                Color bg = new Color(245, 0, 0);
                index = newIdex;
                if (list.getModel().getElementAt(index) == value.toString()) {
                    setForeground(bg);

                } else {
                    setForeground(list.getForeground());
                }

                return this;
            }

        });
    }
}
```

The class MainControllerImpl knows about all the 2 other classes :

```
public class MainControllerImpl implements MainController {

    private UI_Display uiDisplay;
    private UserMainFunctions userMainFuncions;
    private int currentIndex;

    public MainControllerImpl(UI_Display uiDisplay, UserMainFunctions userMainFunctions) {
        this.uiDisplay = uiDisplay;
        this.userMainFuncions = userMainFunctions;
        this.uiDisplay.getSongNameLabel().setFont(new Font("Liquid Crystal", Font.BOLD, 24));
        this.uiDisplay.getSongNameLabel().setForeground(new Color(240, 30, 50));
        this.listenForButtons();
        this.listenForMouseClicks();

    }
    public MainControllerImpl() {

    }
    ActionListener aListener = new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            JButton sourceBtn = (JButton) e.getSource();
            switch (sourceBtn.getText()) {
            case "Pause":

                break;
            case "Play":
                userMainFuncions.play(userMainFuncions.getCurrentPath());
                setSongDisplay();
                break;
            case "Stop":
                userMainFuncions.stop();
                uiDisplay.getSongNameLabel().setText("Music Stopped!");
                break;
            case "Open":
                userMainFuncions.setCurrentPath(uiDisplay.openFileDialog());
                userMainFuncions.play(userMainFuncions.getCurrentPath());
                setSongDisplay();
                break;
            case "OpenDir":
                List<String> songList = uiDisplay.openDir();
                load_JList(songList);
                break;
            case "Prev":
                decrementList();
                break;
            case "Next":
                incrementList();
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }
        }
    };

    public void load_JList(List<String> songList) {
        if (songList != null) {
            DefaultListModel<String> loadedList = new DefaultListModel<String>();
            for (String s : songList) {
                loadedList.addElement(s);
            }
            uiDisplay.getjList_songList().setModel(loadedList);
            uiDisplay.getjList_songList().setVisibleRowCount(uiDisplay.getjList_songList().getModel().getSize());
            uiDisplay.getjList_songList().setSelectedIndex(0);
            uiDisplay.setCellRenderer(getCurrentIndex());
            userMainFuncions.setCurrentPath(uiDisplay.getjList_songList().getSelectedValue());
            userMainFuncions.play(userMainFuncions.getCurrentPath());
            while(userMainFuncions.getPlayer().isComplete()) {
                System.out.println("asdkjfhsdogfh");
            }

            setSongDisplay();

        }
    }

    public void incrementList() {
        if (getCurrentIndex() < uiDisplay.getjList_songList().getModel().getSize()) {
            setCurrentIndex(getCurrentIndex() + 1);
        }
        if (getCurrentIndex() == uiDisplay.getjList_songList().getModel().getSize()) {
            setCurrentIndex(0);
        }
        userMainFuncions.setCurrentPath(uiDisplay.getjList_songList().getModel().getElementAt(getCurrentIndex()));
        uiDisplay.setCellRenderer(getCurrentIndex());
        userMainFuncions.play(userMainFuncions.getCurrentPath());
        // uiDisplay.getjList_songList().setCellRenderer(renderCells);

    }
    public void decrementList() {
        if (getCurrentIndex() < uiDisplay.getjList_songList().getModel().getSize()&&getCurrentIndex()!=0) {
            setCurrentIndex(getCurrentIndex() - 1);
        }
        else if (getCurrentIndex() == 0) {
            setCurrentIndex(uiDisplay.getjList_songList().getModel().getSize()-1);
        }
        userMainFuncions.setCurrentPath(uiDisplay.getjList_songList().getModel().getElementAt(getCurrentIndex()));
        uiDisplay.setCellRenderer(getCurrentIndex());
        userMainFuncions.play(userMainFuncions.getCurrentPath());
        // uiDisplay.getjList_songList().setCellRenderer(renderCells);

    }

    @Override
    public void listenForButtons() {
        this.uiDisplay.getBtnPause().addActionListener(aListener);
        this.uiDisplay.getBtnPlay().addActionListener(aListener);
        this.uiDisplay.getBtnStop().addActionListener(aListener);
        this.uiDisplay.getBtnOpenDir().addActionListener(aListener);
        this.uiDisplay.getBtnEjectOpen().addActionListener(aListener);
        this.uiDisplay.getBtnPrev().addActionListener(aListener);
        this.uiDisplay.getBtnNext().addActionListener(aListener);
    }

    MouseListener mouseListener = new MouseListener() {

        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            if (e.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON1) {
                // System.out.println(uiDisplay.getjList_songList().getSelectedValue());

            }
            if (e.getClickCount() == 2) {
                setCurrentIndex(uiDisplay.getjList_songList().getSelectedIndex());
                uiDisplay.setCellRenderer(getCurrentIndex());
                userMainFuncions.setCurrentPath(uiDisplay.getjList_songList().getSelectedValue());
                userMainFuncions.play(userMainFuncions.getCurrentPath());
                setSongDisplay();
            }

        }
    };

    public void listenForMouseClicks() {
        this.uiDisplay.getjList_songList().addMouseListener(mouseListener);
    }

    private void setSongDisplay() {
        if (userMainFuncions.getCurrentPath() != null) {
            List<String> id3v1tag_List = userMainFuncions.getID3V1TAG(userMainFuncions.getCurrentPath());
            if (id3v1tag_List.size() > 2) {
                uiDisplay.getSongNameLabel().setText(id3v1tag_List.get(2) + " " + id3v1tag_List.get(4));
            } else
                uiDisplay.getSongNameLabel().setText(userMainFuncions.getCurrentPath());
        }
    }

    public int getCurrentIndex() {
        return currentIndex;
    }

    public void setCurrentIndex(int currentIndex) {
        this.currentIndex = currentIndex;
    }


}
```

How can i run a method like "increment" inside that thread (in the while loop), without breaking the SRP ?

Many thanks guys!

Comment: You can do it by yourself, when you read about [concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html)

Comment: And: please spend the time to properly format **all** your code input for your readers.

Comment: I’m thinking a observer pattern might be generally a better approach

Comment: What’s “Player”?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of checking is complete in the same thread you can return some Boolean when completed and capture it in Future. Then Future.get will wait until playing thread returns after completing the song.